# How to filter on calculated column of a query and meanwhile preserve mapped entities

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a query which selects an entity A and some calculated fields

```
q = session.query(Recipe,func.avg(Recipe.somefield).join(.....)
```

I then use what I select in a way which assumes I can subscript result with "Recipe" string:

```
for entry in q.all():
   recipe=entry.Recipe # Access KeyedTuple by Recipe attribute
   ...
```

Now I need to wrap my query in an additional select, say to filter by calculated field AVG:

```
q=q.subquery(); 
q=session.query(q).filter(q.c.avg_1 > 1)
```

And now I cannot access entry.Recipe anymore!
Is there a way to make SQLAlchemy adapt a query to an enclosing one, like `aliased(adapt_on_names=True) or`select_from_entity()`?
I tried using those but was given an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael Bayer mentioned in a relevant Google Group thread, such adaptation is already done via `Query.from_self()` method. My problem was that in this case I didn't know how to refer a column which I want to filter on

This is due to the fact, that it is calculated i.e. there is no table to refer to!

I might resort to using literals(`.filter('avg_1>10')`), but 'd prefer to stay in the more ORM-style

So, this is what I came up with - an explicit column expression

```
row_number_column = func.row_number().over(
    partition_by=Recipe.id
).label('row_number')

query = query.add_column(
    row_number_column
)
query = query.from_self().filter(row_number_column == 1)
```